# Key Value Pair implementation C

Tags: c++, char, double, key-value, keyvaluepair

I have a `.txt` file that stores student names along with two of their best marks. If a student for some reason, i.e. dropping out of course, fails to pass a course, then no marks are recorded.

My file looks like this

```
Samuel= 90.5, 95.9
Bill= 25.2, 45.3
Tim
Anthony= 99.9, 12.5
Mark
Rob
```

Basically, `Tim`, `Mark` and `Rob` failed the course and hence their marks are not stored. Also to differentiate between a failed mark and a pass mark, I have used the `=` symbol. Basically, I want to store all the names into memory alongside their associated values.

This is my implementation, however it is flawed in the sense that I have declared a `double *marks[2]` array to store all six marks, when clearly it will only store 3. I am having trouble storing the values into the `double` array.

This is my code...

```
istream& operator>> (istream& is, Students& student)
{
    student.names = new char*[6];
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
    {
     student.names[i] = new char[256];
     student.marks[i] = new double[2];
     is.getline(student.names[i], sizeof(student.names));

     for (int j=0; j < 256; j++)
     {
        if((student.names[i][j] == '='))
        {
            int newPos = j + 1;
            for (int k = newPos; k < 256; k++)
            {
                student.names[i][k - newPos] = student.names[k];
            }   
         }
      }
   }
}
```

How can I go about storing the values of the students with the valid marks? Please, no use of `vectors` or `stringstreams`, just pure C/C++ `char arrays`

Comment: @Silicomancer, no it's not homework. Just self teaching and learning, if it was homework I would have asked my lecturer for help

Comment: You can just use getline to read lines and stringstream to assign the read data into names and numbers. You can use an unordered_map with the string as key that maps to vector of values (doubles). Hope this helps.

Comment: @learningToCode, Is there a way of doing it without `stringstream` and `vectors`?

Comment: `-1` because asking for code golf solutions isn't solving "practical, real problems".

Comment: `+1` because coding is like writing, you have to read a whole lot of it before you could ever write it.

Comment: if for some reason you want to keep using c-string tools then you have take a look at C functions `sscanf` or `atof`, whichever you find more to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

You have a few options, you could use a `struct` like so

```
struct Record {
    std::string name;
    double marks[2];
};
```

And then stick that into something like `std::vector<Record>` or an array of them like

```
Records *r = new Records[1000];
```

You could also keep three different arrays (either automatically allocated or dynamically allocated or even `std::vector`), one to hold the name, two to hold the marks.

In each case you would just indicate a fail by some thing like the marks being zero.

Also, you can use

```
std::string name;
double first, second;
std::cin >> name;
if (name[name.size() - 1] == '=')
    std::cin >> first >> second;
```

And this will parse the input like you want it to for a single line.  Once you've done that you can wrap the whole thing in a loop while sticking the values you get into some sort of data structure that I already described.

Hope that gives you a few ideas on where to go!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will consider this as an alternative answer, however I would greatly appreciate it if you could help me solve it using my `istream` and no `vectors`. It would mean a lot if you helped me out

Comment: @SamThers You don't need vectors at all, vectors are just there for storing the data once you get it.  You could use an array if you really wanted to.  The only reason that I suggested vectors is because you can keep growing them without having to worry about running out of space.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. What about storing just valid numbers. I don't want store any blanks, and I don't want to leave them as `0`

Comment: @SamThers You can either omit them entirely from what ever data structure you're using (so there's no record of the student ever being enrolled) or you can add a boolean flag to tell whether or not the student has failed.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strategy:

First of all you need to implement a `struct` to hold the key-value pair, I suggest the following:

```
struct Student {
    char name[30];
    double marks[2];
};
```

Note that you can give the dimension of the char array inside the `struct` if you know that the length will never be higher. (which is given here)

Now what you need is to know how many lines are in your `ifstream`, you could make a loop of `is.getline()` calls to get there. (don't forget to call `is.clear()` and `is.seekg(0)` when finished, to be at the beginning for the real loop)

When you know how many lines are in your ifstream you can use dynamically cast the Array of your `struct` with the actual length of your file:

```
Student * students = new Student[lineCount]; // line count of is
```

As you can see, there's no need to have a `std::vector` to hold the values. Consider that the `getline()` loop may be an overkill just to get the line count, alternatively you could give a length to Students at compile-time by making an array with a length that will never be overpassed. 
(e.g. `Student students[128];`)

Now you need to parse the lines, i'd suggest you make a loop like the following (line by line):

```
// int parseLine ( char* line, char* name, double* marks ) { ...   
bool hasMarks=false;
int iLine=0; // Line pos iterator
int iName=0; // Name pos iterator
char mk1Str[4]; // String buffer, Mark 1
char mk2Str[4]; // String buffer, Mark 2

while(line[iLine]!='\0')
{
    if(line[iLine]=='=')
    {
        hasMarks=true;
        name[iLine]='\0';

        for(int iMark=0;iMark<4;iMark++)
        {
            mk1Str[iMark]=line[iLine+iMark+2];
            mk2Str[iMark]=line[iLine+iMark+8];
            // ^^ You can harcode the offsets (2,8) since they don't change 
        }
        break;
    }
    name[iName++]=line[iLine]; 
    iLine++;
}
```

Now what you need is to parse the marks to `double` values, for this you could use the `atof()` function that works with `char*`. The bool `hasMarks` helps you know if a student has defined marks, if not, you could define dummy values like -1 for the mark fields of your `struct`.

I think this works quite well for your case...